# pythonic way to update two variables with same value

Tags: python

My code

```
  time_last_job_done = time.time()
  time_last_log_progress = time.time()
```

If i am making an update to 2 variables. Is there a more pythonic way to do this? I know something like this can be done

```
time_last_job_done = time_last_log_progress = time.time()
```

However i am wondering which one is more readable for the long term

I realize there was confusion so adding more code to get better context

```
def _retrieve_all_done_messages(
    done_queue, task: str, job_msgs: Set[str], timeout_secs: int
) -> None:
    """
    Returns when job done message has been received for every job in `job_msgs`.
    Raises exception if unknown job is found or timeout is exceeded.
    The timeout period measures time since last job completed, so the timeout setting
    should be based on typical runtime for a single job, and not the full batch.
    """
    job_done_msgs: Set[str] = set()
    time_last_job_done = time.time()
    time_last_log_progress = time.time()

    while len(job_done_msgs) < len(job_msgs):
        # SQS long polling
        # https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-short-and-long-polling.html#sqs-long-polling
        job_done_sqs_messages = done_queue.receive_messages(
            WaitTimeSeconds=WAIT_TIME, MaxNumberOfMessages=10
        )
        new_job_done_msgs = {message.body for message in job_done_sqs_messages}

        if not new_job_done_msgs.issubset(job_msgs):
            raise UnknownJobException(new_job_done_msgs=new_job_done_msgs)

        job_done_msgs = job_done_msgs | new_job_done_msgs

        for job_done_sqs_message in job_done_sqs_messages:
            job_done_sqs_message.delete()

        if len(new_job_done_msgs) > 0:
            # Reset timeout
            time_last_job_done = time.time()
            # Log progress
            msg = f"Done so far: {len(job_done_msgs)} / {len(job_msgs)}. "
            logger.info(msg, extra={"example_job_done": new_job_done_msgs.pop()})
            # Send progress monitor updates every 30mins
            if time.time() > time_last_log_progress + (30 * 60):
                time_last_log_progress = time.time()
                log_progress(f"{task} - {msg}")

        # Check timeout
        if time.time() > time_last_job_done + timeout_secs:
            raise BatchTimeoutException(
                jobs_not_done=(job_msgs - job_done_msgs), timeout_secs=timeout_secs
            )
```

Comment: If they have the same value, why would you need two variables?

Comment: Note that `time.time()` could change between the two calls, so if your intent is for them to be the same you must use the second example.

Comment: They both take on different values but are initialized as same?

Comment: Why is the way you showed "unpythonic"? `a = b = time.time()` works perfectly fine and its meaning is very clear. I see nothing wrong with it.

Comment: `a = b = c` is fine for immutable values; `a = b = []` is not the same as `a = []; b = []`, though.

Comment: I would probably prefer `a = c; b = c`, though, on two line lines.

Comment: Has nothing to do with pythonic, because correct logic is more important.`a = b = time.time()` means `a == b`, but `a = time.time() b = time.time()` means `a != b`, the values returned by the two `time` function calls are different although the time gap is small.

Comment: time_last_job_done get's reset and time_last_log_progress is used for another purpose

Comment: @K.Prot Although in the code, they're never compared with each other, so it shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: @wjandrea But they are compared with other variables. If the logic or requirements require them to be the same, then `a = time.time() b = time.time()` may be wrong.

Comment: @wjandrea that makes sense too does my   if time.time() > time_last_log_progress + (30 * 60) make sense ? feel free to post answer so i can upvote and accept, a lot of great answers in the comments.

Comment: Are you wondering just about the assignment? "Pythonic" would likely also involve using shorter names. E.g. practically every local is called ``*_job_*`` which could be dropped. Just having ``last_done = last_log = time.time()`` would be a large improvement not from dropping a line but removing naming noise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, they're not functionally equivalent, since the return value of `time.time()` could change. But your code never compares the two variables directly with each other, so this point might not matter.

The **canonical** way to assign two variables the same value is the second snippet you posted:

```
time_last_job_done = time_last_log_progress = time.time()
```

Although this is a bit hard to read since the variable names are a bit long. Consider shortening them, for example:

```
last_job = last_log = time.time()
```

If the names have to stay long, you could also consider a third option:

```
time_last_job_done = time.time()
time_last_log_progress = time_last_job_done
```

This is a bit more readable having one assignment per line, plus it makes sure that the two variables are identical, but the second line could be confusing since the two variables do different things, and could get missed during refactoring. So if there's any question, go with the canonical way.

(Also note that the answer would be different if you were asking about a mutable value.)

<sub>*Due credit to everyone who commented on the question for informing this answer: [Mark Ransom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5987/mark-ransom), [Pranav Hosangadi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/843953/pranav-hosangadi), [chepner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1126841/chepner), [K.Prot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6212341/k-prot),  [MisterMiyagi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5349916/mistermiyagi)*</sub>